# Activity no abre cuando antes lo hacía

Tags: validación, activity, null

Uso Android Studio 3, de la parte inicial salen dos activities usando dos botones: Cliente y Tipo Transacción, hasta ahí funcionaba bien, pero cuando en MainActivity traté de poner una validación para campos vacíos en Cliente, esta activity ya no abre.

MainActity

```
package com.example.jhon.cesde6;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editDocIdent;

    Button butIngresarCliente;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editDocIdent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDocIdent);

        butIngresarCliente = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butCliente);

        butIngresarCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String docIdent = editDocIdent.getText().toString();
                if(docIdent.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Documento de identidad no puede estar vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClienteIngresadoClase.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    public void ejecutar_cliente(View view){
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this, ClienteClase.class);
        startActivity(i3);
    }

    public void ejecutar_tipo_transaccion(View view){
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, TipoTransaccionClase.class);
        startActivity(i2);
    }

    /*
    public void ejecutar_cliente_ingresado(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ClienteIngresadoClase.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void ejecutar_tipo_transaccion_ingresada(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TipoTransaccionIngresadaClase.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    */

    public void ejecutar_salir(View view){
        finish();
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Banco Cesde"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.419"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butCliente"
    android:layout_width="151dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:onClick="ejecutar_cliente"
    android:text="Cliente"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.414"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butTipoTransaccion"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:onClick="ejecutar_tipo_transaccion"
    android:text="Tipo Transaccion"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.403"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/butCliente" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butSalir"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:onClick="ejecutar_salir"
    android:text="Salir"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.457"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/butTipoTransaccion" />
```

En esta línea `String docIdent = editDocIdent.getText().toString();`
obtengo:

```
v=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{ec6a348 VFED..C.. ...P.... 264,409-717,598 #7f070022 app:id/butCliente}

butIngresarCliente android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{ec6a348 VFED..C.. ...P.... 264,409-717,598 #7f070022 app:id/butCliente}
editDocIdent= null
```

cliente.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDocIdent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Documento de identidad"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTelefono"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Teléfono"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editDireccion" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editFechaIngreso"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Fecha de ingreso"
    android:inputType="date"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTelefono" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editEstado" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butIngresarCliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="validar"
    android:text="Ingresar Cliente"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Nombre"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editDocIdent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editApellido"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Apellido"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editNombre" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDireccion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Dirección"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editApellido" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editEstado"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Estado"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editFechaIngreso" />
```

Comment: De nuevo, necesitamos la traza para ver cuál es el error que te da. Parece que te pasa algo similar a lo que en otra pregunta tuya: revisa que ni el valor de editDocIdent ni el de editDocIdent.getText() sea nulo

Comment: Sí, en esta línea, llega nulo   butIngresarCliente = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butCliente);

Comment: ¿Cuál es nulo: butIngresarCliente o editDocIdent?

Comment: Los dos, lo mismo que savedInstanceState

Comment: Pon el código del layout activity_main

Comment: Listo, arriba quedó luego de editar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83439/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-jhon-hernandez).

Comment: En tu  `activity_main` te falta agregar  `EditText`, y seria conveniente agregar la etiqueta android, y eliminar  android-studio ya que solo se utiliza referente a problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema es que en el xml no existe ningun id que sea editDocIdent asi que el find siempre va a dar null y cuando intentas hacer el getText() falla. Agrega el EditText al xml y deberia funcionar.

El codigo en si esta bien solo esta mal puesto, mueve estas lineas de codigo del MainActivity al ClienteClase que es el activity donde estan los EditText

```
    butIngresarCliente = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butCliente);

    butIngresarCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String docIdent = editDocIdent.getText().toString();
            if(docIdent.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Documento de identidad no puede estar vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClienteIngresadoClase.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: editDocIdent es de la activity cliente.xml  @Erick Silva

Comment: cuando haces (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDocIdent); lo hace sobre el layout cargado en el activity en el que se ejecuta, en tu caso vos estas usando setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); entonces el edit debeDocIdent debe pertenecer a ese layout, de lo contrario no lo podra encontrar y devolvera null

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto... ¿cómo debería quedar el código? @Erick Silva

Comment: bueno, eso depende de lo que vos quieras exactamente, por lo que veo si el dni no fue ingresado correctamente queres mostrar un toast y no abrir la pantalla de cliente, pero el dni se ingresa en la pantalla de cliente. Entonces la pregunta es, como queres que se comporte exactamente?
Podrias tener los editText en el main, pero entonces no tendria sentido la pantalla de cliente o podrias validar el dni en la pantalla de cliente y no en el  main, sino usar la validacion para cuando quiera guardar los datos por ejemplo.

Comment: El último caso, quiero validar cuando vaya a guardar los datos @Erick Silva

Comment: Ahi edite la respuesta, espero que te sirva

Comment: Cierto, ahora funciona.